# How to create a layout?

Tags: android, layout, view, drawable

I am trying to display the triangle with nodes similar to this picture in my Android app

[image]

And I have only two drawables. First is of circle and second one is of line.
I have searched a lot on internet but not getting any solution to which layout I should use and how I can achieve display this triangle on Android.

I cannot take an entire image of this triangle as in the place of nodes that would be some dynamic data displayed at run time.

Comment: Why not using custom views?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom view with the help of Android [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) and its methods [`drawLines()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines(float[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint)) and [`drawCircle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

Here is how to create [Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#custom) and here is a very nice, short [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) on how to use these methods to draw any shape.

Sample

```
// somewhere in the constructor, call this
private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    // mPaint.setStrokeWidth(SOME_VALUE);
    ...
}

// override onSizeChanged() to make your measurements.
// if you need 'finer' control, override onMeasure(), but be careful with that one
// (read its javadocs before you override it).
// measurements include shape and text locations and sizes, etc.
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mTriangleVertices[0] = 0.2  * w; // x0
    mTriangleVertices[1] = 0.15 * h; // y0

    mTriangleVertices[2] = 0.5  * w; // x1
    mTriangleVertices[3] = 0.85 * h; // y1

    mTriangleVertices[4] = 0.8  * w; // x2
    mTriangleVertices[5] = 0.15 * h; // y2
    // other calculations...
}

// after you save your measurements to some fields, override onDraw().
// use all the tools you created and the info you gathers above here.
// avoid creating objects at all cost. read the docs for more info.
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); // include this first, last or you can even omit it sometimes

    canvas.drawLines(mTriangleVertices, 0, mTriangleVertices.length, mPaint);

    // canvas.drawCircle(); canvas.drawOval(); etc..
}
```